# Istanbul coverage issue "else path not taken" but clearly is

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, babeljs, istanbul, nyc

I have this piece of code below, and I am using `nyc` and `babel` to create a coverage report.

For some reason the report is giving me an issue "else path not taken" but there's nothing I can do to stop this.

Why is this here? How can I make it go away?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because I didn't have any code that was continuing past all of these returns. I moved the `return false` to the bottom and it worked.

Comment: I have a similar problem. In a simple function, `foo(x: SomeType) { if (!x) {return '';} return 'something non empty';` I have two tests for empty and non-empty respectively but it still says `if(!x)` 'path not taken; tests partially covered'. Any idea why?